# How to create a route in express and receive a response (`Cannot GET/api/example')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

When I try to reference `http://localhost: 8000/api/example` I receive the message `Cannot GET/api/example` (Not Found 404) in Postman. My goal is to receive a reply message:

```
{
   data: 'You hit example endpoint'
}
```

In Postman I set in `headers Content-Type: application/json`

---

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('api/example', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        data: 'You hit data endpoint'
    });
});

const port = process.env.port || 8000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`connect on the port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Add the leading slash on your route and change `app.get('api/example', ...)` to `app.get('/api/example', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> app.get('api/example', (req, res) => {
> ```

You are requesting `/api/example` not `api/example`. You need to specify the `/` at the start of the route.

---

> In Postman I set in headers `Content-Type: application/json`

You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the type of.

Do not confuse the `Content-Type` request header with the `Content-Type` response header or the `Accept` request header.